# discord.py: How do I avoid deletion of all the previous commands' output and processing new command twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use the following method to simultaneously wait for either a reaction add or a message edit. For reference, I'm using discord.py v2.0.0a, and my command is in a cog:

```py
@commands.command(name="test")
async def test_(self, ctx, *, input):

    ... (lines omitted)

    err_msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed_err)
    out_img = await ctx.send(image)
    await out_img.add_reaction(emo_del)

    def rct_check(reaction, user):
        return reaction.message.id == out_img.id and user == ctx.author

    def edit_check(before, after):
        return before.content != after.content and before.id == after.id

    while True:
        tasks = [
                asyncio.create_task(self.bot.wait_for(
                    "reaction_add",
                    timeout=timeout_,
                    check=rct_check
                    ), name="rct_add"),
                asyncio.create_task(self.bot.wait_for(
                    "message_edit",
                    timeout=timeout_,
                    check=edit_check
                    ), name="msg_edit")
                ]

        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

        finished: asyncio.Task = list(done)[0]

        for task in pending:
            try:
                task.cancel()
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                pass

        for task in done:
            task.exception()

        action = finished.get_name()
        try:
            result = finished.result()
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await out_img.clear_reactions()
            break

        if action == "rct_add":
            reaction, user = result

            if str(reaction.emoji) == emo_del:
                if out_img is not None:
                    await out_img.delete()
                if err_msg is not None:
                    await err_msg.delete()
                break

        elif action == "msg_edit":
            before, after = result

            if out_img is not None:
                await out_img.delete()
            if err_msg is not None:
                await err_msg.delete()
            await self.bot.process_commands(after)
            break
```

Suppose the bot's prefix is `!` and the name of the command is `test`:

```
User: !test 1
Bot: output 1
User: !test 2
Bot: output 2
```

When I edit `!test 2` to say `!test 3` for example, I expect that the bot only deletes `output 2` and replies with `output 3` like so:

```
User: !test 1
Bot: output 1
User: !test 3 (edited)
Bot: output 3
```

But what actually happens is that the bot deletes both `output 1` and `output 2` and replies with `output 3` two times, resulting in this:

```
User: !test 1
User: !test 3 (edited)
Bot: output 3
Bot: output 3
```

If someone could point me in the right direction here as to what I've done wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you indented your code (`while True:`) properly? Where is the `test` command?

Comment: To my knowledge, I have indented it properly. Is there something wrong with the indentation? As for where the `test` command is, the actual command I'm implementing this function in is much larger, so I omitted the rest of the code for brevity, and I'm using `test` as an example name. But if you want me to include the whole command, I can do that.

Comment: Sorry, but didn't notice the `self.bot.wait_for()`. Are you using Cogs or something; why else would you add the `self` before the `bot.wait_for()`? I've not used Cogs before, so have no idea what that is. Hoping the case is the same for `discord.Bot`s: my IDE warned me about `list(done)[0]`, saying "Expected type 'Task', got 'Future' instead". Looks like done is of the type `Future`, but it probably needs to match with `asyncio.Task`, which is not of the type `Future`. I removed the `self.` everywhere to get this.

Comment: That is correct, I'm in a cog.

Comment: So, is the error correct or is it not the problem?

Comment: I *think* that this is not the problem. Although, after doing more research, I'm starting to think that the solution to this problem is much more complicated than I'd hoped.